# Shadcn Toasts (Inspired by react-hot-toast library) duration issues

Tags: typescript, next.js

## In a 13.4 Nextjs project (app router), using Typescript and TailwindCSS.

I'm trying to use the toasts provided by the (incredible) shadcnUI Library.
It is inspired by the react-hot-toast and bring the saucy flavor this library is famous for.

I had no problem with the general implementation of the toast's functionality.
However, thing changed when I tried to add a timer bar at the bottom of each toast, showing the duration of the toast.
I've managed to show the timer bar (a custom progress bar element) and to make it correspond the duration of each toast.

But while doing so, I remarked that the duration of the toast was actually not the one I gave it as props, neither the one given through the TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY const set in the use-toast.ts of the shadcn component.

I tried different settings, but it appears that the Toaster has a default value (given by the root toaster from react-hot-toast) of 5000ms (5s) and that the "duration" value passed as props in the actual Toast doe not override it.
At least this is what I figured so far.
After messing up a bit with the provided code, I can not manage to pass the duration prop and to make it count as the only duration value to use for the Toaster (except if null, then default value ofc).

Anyway, for those kind enough to help me out...

Here is the use toast:

```
import * as React from "react"

import type {
  ToastActionElement,
  ToastProps,
} from "@/components/ui/toast"

const TOAST_LIMIT = 3
export const TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY = 2000

type ToasterToast = ToastProps & {
  id: string
  title?: React.ReactNode
  description?: React.ReactNode
  action?: ToastActionElement
  duration?: number
}

const actionTypes = {
  ADD_TOAST: "ADD_TOAST",
  UPDATE_TOAST: "UPDATE_TOAST",
  DISMISS_TOAST: "DISMISS_TOAST",
  REMOVE_TOAST: "REMOVE_TOAST",
} as const

let count = 0

function genId() {
  count = (count + 1) % Number.MAX_VALUE
  return count.toString()
}

type ActionType = typeof actionTypes

type Action =
  | {
    type: ActionType["ADD_TOAST"]
    toast: ToasterToast
  }
  | {
    type: ActionType["UPDATE_TOAST"]
    toast: Partial<ToasterToast>
  }
  | {
    type: ActionType["DISMISS_TOAST"]
    toastId?: ToasterToast["id"]
  }
  | {
    type: ActionType["REMOVE_TOAST"]
    toastId?: ToasterToast["id"]
  }

interface State {
  toasts: ToasterToast[]
}

const toastTimeouts = new Map<string, ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>()
const addToRemoveQueue = (toastId: string) => {
  if (toastTimeouts.has(toastId)) {
    return
  }

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), "REMOVE_TOAST:", toastId )
    toastTimeouts.delete(toastId)
    dispatch({
      type: "REMOVE_TOAST",
      toastId: toastId,
    })
  }, TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY)

  toastTimeouts.set(toastId, timeout)
}

export const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TOAST":
      console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),"ADD_TOAST", action.toast.id, "duration:", action.toast.duration);
      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: [action.toast, ...state.toasts].slice(0, TOAST_LIMIT),
      }

    case "UPDATE_TOAST":
      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: state.toasts.map((t) =>
          t.id === action.toast.id ? { ...t, ...action.toast } : t
        ),
      }

    case "DISMISS_TOAST": {
      const { toastId } = action

      // ! Side effects ! - This could be extracted into a dismissToast() action,
      // but I'll keep it here for simplicity
      console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString() ,"DISMISS_TOAST:", toastId, "duration:", state.toasts[0].duration)
      if (toastId) {
        addToRemoveQueue(toastId)
      } else {
        state.toasts.forEach((toast) => {
          addToRemoveQueue(toast.id)
        })
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: state.toasts.map((t) =>
          t.id === toastId || toastId === undefined
            ? {
              ...t,
              open: false,
            }
            : t
        ),
      }
    }
    case "REMOVE_TOAST":
      if (action.toastId === undefined) {
        return {
          ...state,
          toasts: [],
        }
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: state.toasts.filter((t) => t.id !== action.toastId),
      }
  }
}

const listeners: Array<(state: State) => void> = []

let memoryState: State = { toasts: [] }

function dispatch(action: Action) {
  memoryState = reducer(memoryState, action)
  listeners.forEach((listener) => {
    listener(memoryState)
  })
}

type Toast = Omit<ToasterToast, "id">

function toast({ ...props }: Toast) {
  const id = genId()

  const update = (props: ToasterToast) =>
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_TOAST",
      toast: { ...props, id },
    })
  const dismiss = () => dispatch({ type: "DISMISS_TOAST", toastId: id })

  dispatch({
    type: "ADD_TOAST",
    toast: {
      ...props,
      id,
      open: true,
      onOpenChange: (open) => {
        if (!open) dismiss()
      },
    },
  })

  return {
    id: id,
    dismiss,
    update,
  }
}

function useToast() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<State>(memoryState)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    listeners.push(setState)
    return () => {
      const index = listeners.indexOf(setState)
      if (index > -1) {
        listeners.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
  }, [state])

  return {
    ...state,
    toast,
    dismiss: (toastId?: string) => dispatch({ type: "DISMISS_TOAST", toastId }),
  }
}

export { useToast, toast }
```

Here is the Toaster:

```
/** @format */

'use client';

import {
  Toast,
  ToastClose,
  ToastDescription,
  ToastProvider,
  ToastTitle,
  ToastViewport,
} from '@/components/ui/toast';
import { useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';
import { TimerBar } from '@/components/ui/timerBar';
import { TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';

export function Toaster() {
  const { toasts } = useToast();

  return (
    <div className="absolute max-w-full">
      <ToastProvider>
        {toasts.map(function ({
          id,
          title,
          description,
          action,
          duration,
          ...props
        }) {
          return (
            <Toast key={id} {...props}>
              <div className="flex flex-col w-full">
                <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full p-2 gap-2 mr-4">
                  <div className="grid gap-1">
                    {title && <ToastTitle>{title}</ToastTitle>}
                    {description && (
                      <ToastDescription>{description}</ToastDescription>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  {action}
                </div>
                <ToastClose />
                <TimerBar max={duration || TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY} />
              </div>
            </Toast>
          );
        })}
        <ToastViewport />
      </ToastProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the Toast (no use but usefull for reproduction)

```
/** @format */

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ToastPrimitives from '@radix-ui/react-toast';
import { cva, type VariantProps } from 'class-variance-authority';
import { Icon } from '@/components/icons/icons';
import { cn } from '@/lib/helpers/utils';

const ToastProvider = ToastPrimitives.Provider;

const ToastViewport = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Viewport>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Viewport>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <ToastPrimitives.Viewport
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'fixed top-0 z-[100] flex max-h-screen w-full flex-col-reverse p-2 right-2 sm:bottom-0 md:top-auto sm:flex-col md:max-w-[420px]',
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));
ToastViewport.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Viewport.displayName;

const toastVariants = cva(
  'group pointer-events-auto relative flex w-full items-center justify-between space-x-4 overflow-hidden rounded-md border p-6 pr-8 shadow-lg transition-all data-[swipe=cancel]:translate-x-0 data-[swipe=end]:translate-x-[var(--radix-toast-swipe-end-x)] data-[swipe=move]:translate-x-[var(--radix-toast-swipe-move-x)] data-[swipe=move]:transition-none data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[swipe=end]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:fade-out-80 data-[state=closed]:slide-out-to-right-full data-[state=open]:slide-in-from-top-full data-[state=open]:sm:slide-in-from-bottom-full',
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        default: 'border bg-background',
        danger: 'danger group border-danger bg-danger-foreground text-danger',
        success:
          'success group border-success bg-success-foreground text-success',
        warning:
          'warning group border-warning bg-warning text-warning-foreground',
        info: 'info group border-info bg-info text-info-foreground',
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: 'default',
    },
  }
);

const Toast = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Root>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Root> &
    VariantProps<typeof toastVariants>
>(({ className, variant, ...props }, ref) => {
  return (
    <ToastPrimitives.Root
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(toastVariants({ variant }), className, 'my-1 mx-2 p-0')}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});
Toast.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Root.displayName;

const ToastAction = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Action>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Action>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <ToastPrimitives.Action
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'inline-flex mr-6 h-8 shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded border bg-transparent px-3 text-sm font-medium ring-offset-background transition-colors hover:bg-secondary focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-ring focus:ring-offset-2 disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50 group-[.danger]:border-muted/40 group-[.danger]:hover:border-danger/30 group-[.danger]:hover:bg-danger group-[.danger]:hover:text-danger-foreground group-[.danger]:focus:ring-danger',
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));
ToastAction.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Action.displayName;

const ToastClose = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Close>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Close>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <ToastPrimitives.Close
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'absolute right-2 top-2 rounded p-1 text-foreground/50 opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:bg-muted hover:text-foreground focus:opacity-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 group-hover:opacity-100 group-[.danger]:text-red-300 group-[.danger]:hover:text-red-50 group-[.danger]:focus:ring-red-400 group-[.danger]:focus:ring-offset-red-600',
      className
    )}
    toast-close=""
    {...props}
  >
    <Icon.close className="h-4 w-4" />
  </ToastPrimitives.Close>
));
ToastClose.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Close.displayName;

const ToastTitle = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Title>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Title>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <ToastPrimitives.Title
    ref={ref}
    className={cn('text-sm font-semibold', className)}
    {...props}
  />
));
ToastTitle.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Title.displayName;

const ToastDescription = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Description>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Description>
  >(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <ToastPrimitives.Description
    ref={ref}
    className={cn('text-sm opacity-90', className)}
    {...props}
    />
));
ToastDescription.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Description.displayName;

type ToastProps = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof Toast>;

type ToastActionElement = React.ReactElement<typeof ToastAction>;

export {
  type ToastProps,
  type ToastActionElement,
  ToastProvider,
  ToastViewport,
  Toast,
  ToastTitle,
  ToastDescription,
  ToastClose,
  ToastAction,
};
```

I did not took the time yet to make a separate repo to test this out (will do if requested), but here is the page i've done to test it out:

```
/** @format */

'use client';

import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { Label } from '@/components/ui/label';
import { ToastAction } from '@/components/ui/toast';
import { useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';
import {useState } from 'react';

interface PageProps {}

export default function Page({}: PageProps) {
  const { toast } = useToast();

  function successToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Success!',
      description: `This is a success toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'success',
      duration: duration,
    });
  }

  function errorToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Error!',
      description: `This is an error toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'danger',
      duration: duration,
    });
  }

  function warningToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Warning!',
      description: `This is a warning toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'warning',
      duration: duration,
    });
  }

  function infoToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Info!',
      description: `This is an info toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'info',
      duration: duration,
    });
  }

  function defaultToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Default!',
      description: `This is a default toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'default',
      duration: duration,
    });
  }

  function actionToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Action!',
      description: `This is an action toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'default',
      duration: duration,
      action: (
        <ToastAction
          onClick={() => alert('Clicked!')}
          className="text-sm"
          altText="Action!"
        >
          Action!
        </ToastAction>
      ),
    });
  }

  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(3000);

  return (
    <div className="max-w-lg flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-4">
      <div className="">
        <Label>Toast duration (in ms)</Label>
        <Input
          value={duration.toString()}
          type="number"
          max={10000}
          placeholder="Duration"
          onChange={(e) => setDuration(parseInt(e.target.value))}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="flex gap-4">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => successToast(duration)}>
            Primary Button
          </Button>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => warningToast(duration)}>
            Secondary Button
          </Button>
          <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => errorToast(duration)}>
            Danger Button
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
          <Button variant="link" onClick={() => defaultToast(duration)}>
            Link Button
          </Button>
          <Button variant="outline" onClick={() => infoToast(duration)}>
            Outline Button
          </Button>
          <Button variant="ghost" onClick={() => actionToast(duration)}>
            Ghost Button
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I already tried different options:

- directly set the TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY const (does not affect the toast duration)
- add another timer to the setTimeout of the addToRemoveQueue

```
const addToRemoveQueue = (toastId: string, delay: number) => {
  if (toastTimeouts.has(toastId)) {
    return
  }

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), "REMOVE_TOAST:", toastId )
    toastTimeouts.delete(toastId)
    dispatch({
      type: "REMOVE_TOAST",
      toastId: toastId,
    })
  }, delay | TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY)

  toastTimeouts.set(toastId, timeout)
}
```

where `delay` is a const passing the duration of the toast
But it appears that not even the basic TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY does not affect the toast duration. It is set by default to 1000000 but the toasts last for 5000 each.

- I've tried to add another timer calling the DISMISS_TOAST action, but this only works for shorter time than 5s, otherwise the one from the Toaster seems to be triggered before.
- I was even wondering this could be a Development Mode issue, but I tried to push it to production and the behavior is quite the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I jsut missed the passing of the prop duration in the Toaster:

```
export function Toaster() {
  const { toasts } = useToast();

  return (
    <div className="absolute max-w-full">
<ToastProvider
      duration={TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY}>
        {toasts. Map(function ({
          id,
          title,
          description,
          action,
          duration,
          ...props
        }) {
          return (
            <Toast key={id} **duration={duration}** {...props}>
              <div className="flex flex-col w-full">
                <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full p-2 gap-2 mr-4">
                  <div className="grid gap-1">
                    {title && <ToastTitle>{title}</ToastTitle>}
                    {description && (
                      <ToastDescription>{description}</ToastDescription>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  {action}
                </div>
                <ToastClose />
                <TimerBar max={duration || TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY} />
              </div>
            </Toast>
          );
        })}
        <ToastViewport />
      </ToastProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For those interested, here are the other files corrected:
use-toast:

```
// Inspired by react-hot-toast library
import * as React from "react"
import type {
  ToastActionElement,
  ToastProps,
} from "@/components/ui/toast"

const TOAST_LIMIT = 3
export const TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY = 3000

type ToasterToast = ToastProps & {
  id: string
  title?: React.ReactNode
  description?: React.ReactNode
  action?: ToastActionElement
  duration?: number
}

const actionTypes = {
  ADD_TOAST: "ADD_TOAST",
  UPDATE_TOAST: "UPDATE_TOAST",
  DISMISS_TOAST: "DISMISS_TOAST",
  REMOVE_TOAST: "REMOVE_TOAST",
} as const

let count = 0

function genId() {
  count = (count + 1) % Number.MAX_VALUE
  return count.toString()
}

type ActionType = typeof actionTypes

type Action =
  | {
    type: ActionType["ADD_TOAST"]
    toast: ToasterToast
  }
  | {
    type: ActionType["UPDATE_TOAST"]
    toast: Partial<ToasterToast>
  }
  | {
    type: ActionType["DISMISS_TOAST"]
    toastId?: ToasterToast["id"]
  }
  | {
    type: ActionType["REMOVE_TOAST"]
    toastId?: ToasterToast["id"]
  }

interface State {
  toasts: ToasterToast[]
}

const toastTimeouts = new Map<string, ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>()
const addToRemoveQueue = (toastId: string) => {
  if (toastTimeouts.has(toastId)) {
    return
  }

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), "REMOVE_TOAST:", toastId )
    toastTimeouts.delete(toastId)
    dispatch({
      type: "REMOVE_TOAST",
      toastId: toastId,
    })
  }, TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY)

  toastTimeouts.set(toastId, timeout)
}

export const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TOAST":
      console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),"ADD_TOAST", action.toast.id, "duration:", action.toast.duration);
      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: [action.toast, ...state.toasts].slice(0, TOAST_LIMIT),
      }

    case "UPDATE_TOAST":
      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: state.toasts.map((t) =>
          t.id === action.toast.id ? { ...t, ...action.toast } : t
        ),
      }

    case "DISMISS_TOAST": {
      const { toastId } = action

      // ! Side effects ! - This could be extracted into a dismissToast() action,
      // but I'll keep it here for simplicity
      console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString() ,"DISMISS_TOAST:", toastId, "duration:", state.toasts[0].duration)
      if (toastId) {
        addToRemoveQueue(toastId)
      } else {
        state.toasts.forEach((toast) => {
          addToRemoveQueue(toast.id)
        })
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: state.toasts.map((t) =>
          t.id === toastId || toastId === undefined
            ? {
              ...t,
              open: false,
            }
            : t
        ),
      }
    }
    case "REMOVE_TOAST":
      if (action.toastId === undefined) {
        return {
          ...state,
          toasts: [],
        }
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: state.toasts.filter((t) => t.id !== action.toastId),
      }
  }
}

const listeners: Array<(state: State) => void> = []

let memoryState: State = { toasts: [] }

function dispatch(action: Action) {
  memoryState = reducer(memoryState, action)
  listeners.forEach((listener) => {
    listener(memoryState)
  })
}

type Toast = Omit<ToasterToast, "id">

function toast({ ...props }: Toast) {
  const id = genId()

  const update = (props: ToasterToast) =>
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_TOAST",
      toast: { ...props, id},
    })
  const dismiss = () => dispatch({ type: "DISMISS_TOAST", toastId: id })

  dispatch({
    type: "ADD_TOAST",
    toast: {
      ...props,
      id,
      open: true,
      onOpenChange: (open) => {
        if (!open) dismiss()
      },
    },
  })

  return {
    id: id,
    dismiss,
    update,
  }
}

function useToast() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<State>(memoryState)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    listeners.push(setState)
    return () => {
      const index = listeners.indexOf(setState)
      if (index > -1) {
        listeners.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
  }, [state])

  return {
    ...state,
    toast,
    dismiss: (toastId?: string) => dispatch({ type: "DISMISS_TOAST", toastId }),
  }
}

export { useToast, toast }
```

```
Toaster:
/** @format */

'use client';

import {
  Toast,
  ToastClose,
  ToastDescription,
  ToastProvider,
  ToastTitle,
  ToastViewport,
} from '@/components/ui/toast';
import { useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';
import { TimerBar } from '@/components/ui/timerBar';
import { TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';

export function Toaster() {
  const { toasts } = useToast();

  return (
    <div className="absolute max-w-full">
      <ToastProvider>
        {toasts.map(function ({
          id,
          title,
          description,
          action,
          duration,
          ...props
        }) {
          return (
            <Toast key={id} duration={duration} {...props}>
              <div className="flex flex-col w-full">
                <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full p-2 gap-2 mr-4">
                  <div className="grid gap-1">
                    {title && <ToastTitle>{title}</ToastTitle>}
                    {description && (
                      <ToastDescription>{description}</ToastDescription>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  {action}
                </div>
                <ToastClose />
                <TimerBar max={duration || TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY} />
              </div>
            </Toast>
          );
        })}
        <ToastViewport />
      </ToastProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
toast:
/** @format */

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ToastPrimitives from '@radix-ui/react-toast';
import { cva, type VariantProps } from 'class-variance-authority';
import { Icon } from '@/components/icons/icons';
import { cn } from '@/lib/helpers/utils';

const ToastProvider = ToastPrimitives.Provider;

const ToastViewport = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Viewport>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Viewport>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <ToastPrimitives.Viewport
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'fixed top-0 z-[100] flex max-h-screen w-full flex-col-reverse p-2 right-2 sm:bottom-0 md:top-auto sm:flex-col md:max-w-[420px]',
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));
ToastViewport.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Viewport.displayName;

const toastVariants = cva(
  'group pointer-events-auto relative flex w-full items-center justify-between space-x-4 overflow-hidden rounded-md border p-6 pr-8 shadow-lg transition-all data-[swipe=cancel]:translate-x-0 data-[swipe=end]:translate-x-[var(--radix-toast-swipe-end-x)] data-[swipe=move]:translate-x-[var(--radix-toast-swipe-move-x)] data-[swipe=move]:transition-none data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[swipe=end]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:fade-out-80 data-[state=closed]:slide-out-to-right-full data-[state=open]:slide-in-from-top-full data-[state=open]:sm:slide-in-from-bottom-full',
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        default: 'border bg-background',
        danger: 'danger group border-danger bg-danger-foreground text-danger',
        success:
          'success group border-success bg-success-foreground text-success',
        warning:
          'warning group border-warning bg-warning text-warning-foreground',
        info: 'info group border-info bg-info text-info-foreground',
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: 'default',
    },
  }
);

const Toast = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Root>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Root> &
    VariantProps<typeof toastVariants>
>(({ className, variant, ...props }, ref) => {
  return (
    <ToastPrimitives.Root
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(toastVariants({ variant }), className, 'my-1 mx-2 p-0')}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});
Toast.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Root.displayName;

const ToastAction = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Action>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Action>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <ToastPrimitives.Action
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'inline-flex mr-6 h-8 shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded border bg-transparent px-3 text-sm font-medium ring-offset-background transition-colors hover:bg-secondary focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-ring focus:ring-offset-2 disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50 group-[.danger]:border-muted/40 group-[.danger]:hover:border-danger/30 group-[.danger]:hover:bg-danger group-[.danger]:hover:text-danger-foreground group-[.danger]:focus:ring-danger',
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));
ToastAction.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Action.displayName;

const ToastClose = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Close>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Close>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <ToastPrimitives.Close
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'absolute right-2 top-2 rounded p-1 text-foreground/50 opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:bg-muted hover:text-foreground focus:opacity-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 group-hover:opacity-100 group-[.danger]:text-red-300 group-[.danger]:hover:text-red-50 group-[.danger]:focus:ring-red-400 group-[.danger]:focus:ring-offset-red-600',
      className
    )}
    toast-close=""
    {...props}
  >
    <Icon.close className="h-4 w-4" />
  </ToastPrimitives.Close>
));
ToastClose.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Close.displayName;

const ToastTitle = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Title>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Title>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <ToastPrimitives.Title
    ref={ref}
    className={cn('text-sm font-semibold', className)}
    {...props}
  />
));
ToastTitle.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Title.displayName;

const ToastDescription = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Description>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof ToastPrimitives.Description>
  >(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <ToastPrimitives.Description
    ref={ref}
    className={cn('text-sm opacity-90', className)}
    {...props}
    />
));
ToastDescription.displayName = ToastPrimitives.Description.displayName;

type ToastProps = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof Toast>;

type ToastActionElement = React.ReactElement<typeof ToastAction>;

export {
  type ToastProps,
  type ToastActionElement,
  ToastProvider,
  ToastViewport,
  Toast,
  ToastTitle,
  ToastDescription,
  ToastClose,
  ToastAction,
};


And the page to test it out:
/** @format */

'use client';

import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { Label } from '@/components/ui/label';
import { ToastAction } from '@/components/ui/toast';
import { TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY, useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';
import {useState } from 'react';

interface PageProps {}

export default function Page({}: PageProps) {
  const { toast } = useToast();

  function successToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Success!',
      description: `This is a success toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'success',
      duration: duration,
    });
  }

  function errorToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Error!',
      description: `This is an error toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'danger',
      duration: duration,
    });
  }

  function warningToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Warning!',
      description: `This is a warning toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'warning',
      duration: duration,
    });
  }

  function infoToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Info!',
      description: `This is an info toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'info',
      duration: duration,
    });
  }

  function defaultToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Default!',
      description: `This is a default toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'default',
      duration: duration,
    });
  }

  function actionToast(duration?: number) {
    toast({
      title: 'Action!',
      description: `This is an action toast of ${duration}ms`,
      variant: 'default',
      duration: duration,
      action: (
        <ToastAction
          onClick={() => alert('Clicked!')}
          className="text-sm"
          altText="Action!"
        >
          Action!
        </ToastAction>
      ),
    });
  }

  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(3000);

  return (
    <div className="max-w-lg flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-4">
      <div className="">
        <Label>Toast duration (in ms)</Label>
        <Input
          value={duration.toString()}
          type="number"
          max={10000}
          placeholder="Duration"
          onChange={(e) => setDuration(parseInt(e.target.value))}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="flex gap-4">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            onClick={() =>
              successToast(duration ? duration : TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY)
            }
          >
            Primary Button
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="secondary"
            onClick={() =>
              warningToast(duration ? duration : TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY)
            }
          >
            Secondary Button
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="danger"
            onClick={() => errorToast(duration ? duration : TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY)}
          >
            Danger Button
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
          <Button
            variant="link"
            onClick={() =>
              defaultToast(duration ? duration : TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY)
            }
          >
            Link Button
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            onClick={() => infoToast(duration ? duration : TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY)}
          >
            Outline Button
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="ghost"
            onClick={() =>
              actionToast(duration ? duration : TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY)
            }
          >
            Ghost Button
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to test it out, don't forget to add the Toaster as ToastPrivider in your RootLayout:

```
return (
    <NextAuthSessionProvider session={session}>
      <html lang="en">
        <body
          className={`${circularBold.variable} ${gambettaReg.variable} ${gambettaSemi.variable} ${nunito.variable} ${inter.variable} font-inter`}
        >
          <ThemeProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="system" enableSystem>
            <main className="flex flex-col justify-between items-center min-h-screen min-w-screen">
              <Header user={session?.user} />
              {children}
              <Footer />
              **<Toaster />**
            </main>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </NextAuthSessionProvider>
  );
}
```